# What does ^# mean in a regular expression for grep?

Tags: bash, debian, grep

I'm trying to understand the `grep` command:

```
#CPU physical: $(lscpu -b -p=Socket | grep -v '^#' | sort -u | wc -l)
```

and it seems quite understandable, the only thing I couldn't get is the control (`^`) before the hash (`#`)?

Comment: lines beginning with `#` - i.e. `^` means *beginning of line*

Comment: many thanks, do you suggest any reference to get through in this regards

Comment: start with `man grep` ... then follow the documentation suggestions for patterns within than man page

Comment: I'd suggest you google for "regular expression tutorial"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the `^` character as meaning "beginning of line", so `^#` matches a `#` *at the beginning of a line* - in other words, a line that is a comment.

By using the `-v` option to `grep`, you select non-matching lines.

In effect, in this case, the command filters out comments.

See [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_04.html) for more information on regexes in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

You should try execute the command without the grep -v command and see the difference.

`grep -v "^#"` - Removes all comments from the lscpu ouput.

Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching line, below you have an example of how you can get the same answer without filtering output:

```
 egrep "physical id" /proc/cpuinfo|sort -u|wc -l
```